# What am I writing wrong?

Tags: powerquery

I have written the followigen forumule in Power Query Excel:

```
if [DATUM_LEVERBAAR_VANAF] >= Date.FromDateTime.LocalNow() 
and [DATUM_LEVERBAAR_TM] = null 
or [DATUM_LEVERBAAR_TM] >= Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow() 
then "Ja" else "Nee"
```

I'll get the Token comma expected error, what am I writing wrong?

Comment: probably you're missing a closing parenthesis here `Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()`

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a closing parenthesis here `Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()`